# Azure b2c authorization return 401 (Unauthorized) in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I'm using Azure AD B2C as the authentication provider for ASP.NET Blazor WASM application and `API`. So the problem is that I'm not able to access the **API** endpoints from the `client` which is Blazor WASM. When I make the request to the API I get 401 (Unauthorized) response.

Here is the console error

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[Organizer.Web.Shared.Models.SuccessResultModel`1[[Organizer.Web.Shared.DTOs.UserDto, Organizer.Web.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], Organizer.Web.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at Organizer.Web.Pages.Authentication.AccountProfile.OnInitializedAsync() in A:\Software_Development\2022\Organizer\Organizer.Web.Pages\Authentication\AccountProfile.razor.cs:line 57
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

B2C Client settings
[image: Azure Client Settings]

B2C API settings
[image]

Blazor Client Appsettings and Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Organizer.API", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7149"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("Organizer.API"));

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(
        "https://mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/60dbe9eb-056c-400d-a98d-c5c95b2bb000/Data.Read");
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
});
```

```json
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_susi",
    "ClientId": "f2161189-4bc6-4c26-99ae-a82b6729ab33",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
}
```

API

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

```json
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://mydomain.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "60dbe9eb-056c-400d-a98d-c5c95b4bb176",
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "1a5a2799-8dde-4236-901f-c37b3d2b9b39",
    "Scopes": "Data.Read",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_susi",
    "CallbackPath": "/authentication/login-callback"
}
```

**Note:** I have changed the guids and URLs for security reasons.

Comment: I can add any additional data if needed

Comment: You are making an HTTPS connection and the connection is completing including the TLS  encryption which uses a certificate.  You are failing the authentication : builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).  The client ID should be the same at client and server for AzureAdB2C

Comment: I tried this and still, I get the same response. And note that I'm not using Hosted blazor wasm solution

Comment: You still have authentication issues.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

- Please make sure scope is correct .scope not configured properly may
  be the reason prevent client app cannot access web API endpoints
- If appId uri is jus api:// client id , use client id  or if it custom
  uri place that while adding scopes like below in place of clientId in
  Program.cs of the Client app :

> ```
> options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes
>     .Add("https://{TENANT}.onmicrosoft.com/{ API app CLIENTID OR custom value}/{DEFAULT Scope}");
> ```

***For ex:***

```
.Add("https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/41xxxa7xxxx-4xxx3-8fxx-6xxxxxxxfd/API.Access");
```

And then please try if you can set  API app for a `matching audience` in the API app settings file (appsettings.json)  which is nothing but `"Audience": https://{TENANT}.onmicrosoft.com/{ API APP CLIENT ID OR CUSTOM VALUE if present}`

***Ex:***

```
{
  "AzureAdb2c": {
    "Authority": " ",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxx1fdxx",
    "ValidateAuthority": true,
    "Audience": "https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/<client/appId>"
     ...
  }
}
```

the end of the Audience need not be scope /{DEFAULT SCOPE}.

- Just to recheckt,please make sure   Instance,Authority, Tenant ID,
  Tenant domain, Client ID, or Redirect URI , are all configured
  correct in your application and that matches the ones in azure portal
- Also please check all `API permissions` which are required are
  granted to access web API endpoints.

**Reference**: [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app with Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0)